# How to decompress Gzip string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, gzip, zlib

Zlib::GzipReader can take "an IO, or IO-like, object." as it's input, as stated in docs.

```
Zlib::GzipReader.open('hoge.gz') {|gz|
  print gz.read
}

File.open('hoge.gz') do |f|
  gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(f)
  print gz.read
  gz.close
end
```

How should I ungzip a string?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The above method didn't work for me.
I kept getting `incorrect header check (Zlib::DataError)` error.  Apparently it assumes you have a header by default, which may not always be the case.

The work around that I implemented was:

```
require 'zlib'
require 'stringio'
gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(resp.body.to_s))    
uncompressed_string = gz.read
```

Comment: Thank you, I was getting the same error and this solved my problem!

Comment: is calling body.to_s redundant?

Answer (score 19):

Zlib by default asumes that your compressed data contains a header.
If your data does NOT contain a header it will fail by raising a Zlib::DataError.

You can tell Zlib to assume the data has no header via the following workaround:

```
def inflate(string)
  zstream = Zlib::Inflate.new(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS)
  buf = zstream.inflate(string)
  zstream.finish
  zstream.close
  buf
end
```

Answer (score 17):

In Rails you can use:

- `ActiveSupport::Gzip.compress("my string")`
- `ActiveSupport::Gzip.decompress()`.

Answer (score 16):

You need [Zlib::Inflate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/index.html) for decompression of a string and Zlib::Deflate for compression

```
  def inflate(string)
    zstream = Zlib::Inflate.new
    buf = zstream.inflate(string)
    zstream.finish
    zstream.close
    buf
  end
```

Answer (score 7):

zstream = Zlib::Inflate.new(16+Zlib::MAX_WBITS)

Comment: Nice one. From [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/Zlib/Inflate.html) "or add 16 to decode only the gzip format (a Zlib::DataError will be raised for a non-gzip stream)"

Answer (score 5):

Using `(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS)`, I got `ERROR: invalid code lengths set` and `ERROR: invalid block type`
The only following works for me, too.

```
Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(response_body)).read
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the answer above to use a Zlib::Deflate

I kept getting broken files (for small files) and it took many hours to figure out that the problem can be fixed using:

```
buf = zstream.deflate(string,Zlib::FINISH)
```

without the the zstream.finish line!

```
def self.deflate(string)
    zstream = Zlib::Deflate.new
    buf = zstream.deflate(string,Zlib::FINISH)
    zstream.close
    buf
end
```

Answer (score 3):

To gunzip content, use following code (tested on 1.9.2)

```
Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(content), :external_encoding => content.encoding).read
```

Beware of encoding problems

Answer (score 3):

We don't need any extra parameters these days. There are `deflate` and `inflate` class methods which allow for quick oneliners like these:

```
>> data = "Hello, Zlib!"
>> compressed = Zlib::Deflate.deflate(data)
=> "x\234\363H\315\311\311\327Q\210\312\311LR\004\000\032\305\003\363"
>> uncompressed = Zlib::Inflate.inflate(compressed)
=> "Hello, Zlib!"
```

I think it answers the question "How should I ungzip a string?" the best. :)

Comment: If you compress and decompress then this will be fine, but it will not be gzip compressed. Just running Zlib::Inflate.inflate(compressed) on gzip compressed data will assume the wrong compression and throw a "incorrect header check" exception.