# Compressing and decompressing the Stack Overflow homepage HTML

Tags: javascript, ruby, encoding, character-encoding, compression

I'm trying to compress HTML with JavaScript and decompress it with Ruby. Some carachters are not being processed correctly however and I'm looking for a way to fix this.

My compression function first turns the html in to a byte array using [this function](https://gist.github.com/3939036). It then compresses the array with the [js-deflate library](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate/blob/master/rawdeflate.js). Finally, the output from that is base64 encoded using [window.btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa).

```
var compress = function(htmlString) {
  var compressed, originalBytes;

  originalBytes = Utils.stringToByteArray(htmlString);
  compressed = RawDeflate.deflate(originalBytes.join(''));
  return window.btoa(compressed);
};
```

On the Ruby end of things I have a `Decompression` class which first base64 decodes the compressed html. It then uses the Ruby `Zlib` standard library to decompress the html. This process is described in [this Stack Overflow question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1361892/574190).

```
require "base64"
require "zlib"

class Decompression
  def self.decompress(string)
    decoded = Base64.decode64(string)
    inflate(decoded)
  end

private

  def self.inflate(string)
    zstream = Zlib::Inflate.new(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS)
    buf = zstream.inflate(string)
    zstream.finish
    zstream.close
    buf
  end
end
```

I'm using this class to inflate compressed html, which was sent to a local server, and write it to a file.

```
decompressed_content = Decompression.decompress(params["compressed_content"])
File.write('decompressed.html', decompressed_content)
```

Then I open the file in the browser to see if it looks correct.

For the most part, this works fine. I can process the Stack Overflow homepage and it comes out like this:

[image: processed Stack Overflow homepage]

You can see there is some problems though. Some characters are not coming out correctly, most notably the down arrow beside my name in the header

[image: down arrow]

and the multiplication signs in the recent tags list

[image: recent tags list]

**How can I fix my code so that these parts of the page are processed properly?**

I have tried to force the encoding of the inflated html to `UTF-8` but it doesn't change anything.

```
  def self.decompress(string)
    decoded = Base64.decode64(string)
    # Forcing the encoding of the output doesn't do anything.
    inflate(decoded).force_encoding('UTF-8')
  end

  def self.decompress(string)
    decoded = Base64.decode64(string)
    # Either does forcing the encoding of the inflate input.
    inflate(decoded.force_encoding('UTF-8'))
  end
```

One key is that the encoding of the string seems to change to `ASCII-8BIT` after it is Base64 decoded:

```
def self.decompress(string)
  p "Before decode: #{string.encoding}"
  decoded = Base64.decode64(string)
  p "After decode: #{decoded.encoding}"
  inflated = inflate(decoded)
  p "After inflate: #{inflated.encoding}"
  inflated
end

# Before decode: UTF-8
# After decode: ASCII-8BIT
# After inflate: ASCII-8BIT
```

**Edits**

Someone asked for the method I use to get the html in the first place. I simply pull it off the page with jQuery:

```
$('html')[0].outerHTML
```

**Edit to show effect of adding a `Content-Type` meta tag to the inflated html**

I added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` to the inflated html. And I now get question mark boxes like this (Chrome browser by the way):

[image: question mark box].

If I inspect the source of my inflated html and compare it to the source of the actual Stack Overflow html I can see that there is a different character being used for the upside-down triangle beside my name.

**Actual SO Source:** `<span class="profile-triangle">&#9662;</span>`
**Inflated Source without meta Content-Type:** `<span class="profile-triangle">¾</span>`
**Inflated source with meta Content-Type:** `<span class="profile-triangle">�</span>`

Comment: Can you also show us how you get the HTML in the first place?

Comment: I edited the bottom of my post to show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding UTF8 encoding to the HTML you get. Like in

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" charset="UTF-8" />
```

I suggest this because I can't actually see it in the source code (ctrl+u on this same page).

EDIT: Turns out you were missing the charset!

Comment: But how would my decompression function be aware of that? All it can see at the input is a compressed string. It doesn't know whether or not the string contains a meta content type tag. It doesn't even know that the string contains html.

Comment: Ah.. of course. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to fix the problem. I edited the question with some results.

Comment: You were really close but it turns out I actually needed to add a `<meta charset="UTF-8">` instead of the `http-equiv` tag.

Comment: Uh, that was really close. :)

Comment: Done :p In fact, you're OK writing the http-equiv and the content values too!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the content type of HTML is determined by both HTTP headers and the HTML code itself.
If you send over only the HTML code, the HTTP header information is lost.

Look at the HTTP headers sent over by StackOverflow:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=60
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:33200
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 23 Oct 2012 17:35:02 GMT
Expires:Tue, 23 Oct 2012 17:36:02 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 23 Oct 2012 17:35:02 GMT
Vary:*
```

As you can see, the Content-type is specified as being `utf-8`. If creating a file, the content-type needs to be set manually using a HTML tag in the HEAD, as @alexandernst suggests.

Answer (score 0):

[alexandernst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940158/alexandernst) was on the right track but what I actually needed to add to the HTML output was a meta charset tag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Once I put that into the HTML output of the Stack Overflow homepage it looks perfect.