# Javascript string compression and PHP/Ruby decompression

Tags: php, javascript, ruby, compression

Is there a Javascript compression and PHP/Ruby decompression library for strings? I need it because I need to send a very long text string using Ajax on a slow upload link to a web server which uses PHP/Ruby as server-side language.

```
var x = $('#sources').html();
// a very-very long text
var xo = x, o = {};
if(x.length>512*1024) {
  x = compress(x);
  o.c = 1;
}
o.x = x;
$.post('target.php',o,function(res){alert(res==xo)});
```

On server side (for example, PHP):

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['c']) && $_POST['c']=='1') {
    $x = decompress($_POST['x']);
  } else {
    $x = $_POST['x'];
  }
  echo $x;
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many JS implementations of the most common compression algorithm, Zip.

For example [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/)

Zip is of course also [supported in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php).

Comment: ah, so i must write it to a file first, then decompress it?

Answer (score 2):

That should do it

http://webdevwonders.com/lzw-compression-and-decompression-with-javascript-and-php/

LZW is good for strings that actually contain human readable text

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you send your files over http, I would suggest that you let your web server handle this by sending file with gzip content-encoding.

If for example you use Apache, you can enable [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html)

If for some reason you can't change your web server configuration, php also has a built-in gzip handler you could use instead. See: [`ob_gzhandler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php)

Edit:

As for client to server, it doesn't look like this is directly supported by any XmlHttpRequest implementations. You could perhaps find a custom gzip compression algorithm for Javascript and then set the request-header to indicate that it's compressed .That way it becomes transparently decoded by the web server and you don't have to do anything special in php.

See this page: [JavaScript implementation of Gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip).

Comment: You can compress answers from the server to the client but can you compress requests too ?

Comment: Good point .. Doesn't look like any XmlHttpRequest implementations supports this.

Comment: I think a problem is that the client doesn't know what compression schemes are handled by the server. This might need a first request just to ask this and so could be painful to handle in javascript.

Comment: In theory yes, but since OP knows which server the client is talking to, it is in fact known.

Answer (score 0):

Running a google search for "ruby decompress string" comes up with this: [How to decompress Gzip string in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361892/how-to-decompress-gzip-string-in-ruby) which is what you're looking for.