# Sending a SOAP XML manually and receiving a HTTP 500 error code and binary data in the response

Tags: asp.net, soap, character-encoding, iis-7.5, savon

I am using ruby to send a SOAP request to a very enterprisey bla bla service, so unfortunately I can not attach any samples, there's nobody to send any server-side logs, nobody knows whats wrong on the provider side or how the actual HTTP requests need to look like (except a single XML example I got, but no HTTP headers), the docs are very Microsoft-centric with C# examples and whatnot ("instantiate AbstractFactoryFactory..." and whatnot), long live enterprise software.

But the bottom line is, eventually I took one of their own XMLs from their logs and sent it via HTTP to the endpoint from the WSDL and sent it to their host using the [Savon gem raw XML option](http://savonrb.com/version2/locals.html) and got a HTTP 500 error from their host and a bunch of non-ascii binary data inside - literally, no ASCII characters are in the body.

I guessed that maybe Savon does some bad magic or that the XML option is not working as expected and I tried sending the same request via Faraday, but got the same thing,

the HTTP response headers says it's a HTTP response, XML encoded, from an ASP.NET host:

```
 "content-type"=>"text/xml; charset=utf-8",
 "server"=>"Microsoft-IIS/7.5",
 "x-aspnet-version"=>"2.0.50727",
 "x-powered-by"=>"ASP.NET",
```

but again, a 440 bytes worth of binaries in the response:

```
method=:post,
body=
  "\x1F\x8B\b\x00\x00...
```

etc.

Am I missing some weird aspect of the SOAP specification and I need to do something to decode this data or has their server gone bonkers from my XML, HTTP headers or something else and I need to ping the provider?

## Update 1

I noticed that their original XML had UTF-16 encoding set, so I tried encoding the raw string to UTF-16, then had Savon spew errors at me about bad data, then I updated encoding in the Savon client config. But I still get HTTP 500 error and binaries as response and if I try to log anything Savon reports a bug:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (US-ASCII regexp with UTF-16 string)
from /home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/log_message.rb:13:in `to_s'
```

Faraday basically reported the same behavior, an binary blob.

## Update 2

I tried piping the encoding to every known encoding, and got nothing, even though the HTTP headers imply the encoding is UTF-8, it obviously isn't

```
Encoding.name_list.map{ |e_in| [ e_in, ( response.body.dup.force_encoding(e_in).encode('utf-8') rescue 'incompatible' ) ] }
```

There is nothing that would indicate the encoding in the WSDL files, the API spec doesn't even mention encoding except that the request XMLs need to be UTF-8 encoding, I tried encoding the body, changing the XML encoding definition, HTTP headers, but still I get the same binary blob, with the same heading (`\x1F\x8B\b\x00\x00`) - so it's not some weird encryption either.

Compression maybe?

I tried with https for good measure and nothing.

## Question

Am I missing some weird aspect of the SOAP specification and I need to do something to decode this data or has their server gone bonkers from my XML, HTTP headers or something else and I need to ping the provider?

Comment: Have you tried to consume the XML response with Nokogiri? I have successfully worked with DOTNET implemented SOAP/WS*.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenRoller, I just tried parsing the request with `Hash.from_xml` and it worked fine, so the XML format should be fine

Answer (score 1):

The response body was compressed! In the end I just gunzipped it and there it was,

[How to decompress Gzip string in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361892/how-to-decompress-gzip-string-in-ruby)